# How to post file content to server using angular file upload and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to send user selected file to server using angular file-upload i see the data printed in angular service but when i see server controller is printing empty object, Any idea what is implemented wrong here or any better approach to send file to server with content ?

Client

```
//Controller.js

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                console.log('file is ');
                console.dir(file);
                var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };

// Service.js in service i see data `file` data is printed 

angular.module('App').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){

        /*var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        console.log('service called', file);*/
        $http.post(uploadUrl,file, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(resp){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

Server

```
//routes.js 

export default function(app) {
  // Insert routes below
  app.post('/fileUpload', require('./api/fileUpload'));
}

//index.js 

    var express = require('express');
    var controller = require('./fileUpload.controller');

    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/fileUpload',controller.create);


    module.exports = router;

//controller.js

    export function create(req, res) {
    console.log('fileUpload controller server',req.body);
    }
```